# c# nest elastic generic index create

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a generic "Create" method. This method will create index by generic type.

```
public void Create<T>(T node) 
{        
    if (!_elasticClient.IndexExists(_indexName).Exists)
    {
        var indexSettings = new IndexSettings();
        indexSettings.NumberOfReplicas = 1;
        indexSettings.NumberOfShards = 3;

        var createIndexDescriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(_indexName)
                .Mappings(ms => ms.Map<T>(m => m.AutoMap()))
                .InitializeUsing(new IndexState() { Settings = indexSettings })
                .Aliases(a => a.Alias(aliasName));

        var response = _elasticClient.CreateIndex(createIndexDescriptor);
    }

    _elasticClient.Index<T>(node, idx => idx.Index(_indexName));
}
```

But I getting errors:

1. The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
   'MappingsDescriptor.Map(Func<TypeMappingDescriptor,
   ITypeMapping>)'
2. The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
   'ElasticClient.Index(T, Func<IndexDescriptor,
   IIndexRequest>)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.Map<T>()` method in nest uses a class constraint for `T`. You need to add the same class constraint to your generic `T`.

```
public void Create<T>(T node)
    where T: class
{
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `where T : class`:

```
public void Create<T>(T node) where T : class
    {        
        if (!_elasticClient.IndexExists(_indexName).Exists)
        {
            var indexSettings = new IndexSettings();
            indexSettings.NumberOfReplicas = 1;
            indexSettings.NumberOfShards = 3;

            var createIndexDescriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(_indexName)
           .Mappings(ms => ms
                           .Map<T>(m => m.AutoMap())
                    )
            .InitializeUsing(new IndexState() { Settings = indexSettings })
            .Aliases(a => a.Alias(aliasName));

            var response = _elasticClient.CreateIndex(createIndexDescriptor);
        }

        _elasticClient.Index<T>(node, idx => idx.Index(_indexName));
    }
}
```

I solved my problem I was having please see below.